# Can I set up a proxy/rewrite in Nextjs13 to redirect fetch requests and avoid CORS?

Tags: next.js, http-proxy, same-origin-policy, next.js13, wavesurfer.js

Total React and Nextjs newb here!

So I've made a little media player app with Nextjs that plays audio directly from public share links from Google Drive. I got it working perferctly fine with the standard HTML  player where I could just use src and input the download link from Google drive. My problems started when I wanted to include Wavesurfer.js which is a library that makes a waveform display from a media file. It works fine locally, but online  it needs to download the files to make the waveform and uses an internal fetch function to do so, and therefore gets blocked by CORS. Is there any way where I can route the fetch requests through my "back end" to get around this problem?

Tried a rewrite where I tricked the fetch request to think it was fetching from my dev server, but I never got it working, or fully understood how to implement rewrites or if it even does what I want it to.

Heres a link to the player component I'm trying to get to work: https://github.com/orjanlund/okr-wavesurfer-player

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.